# golang:Add custom Extension to ClientHelloMsg on crypto/tls

Tags: go, ssl

For some reason I need to add a custom extension to clientHellomsg when using `crypto/tls`.  But I didn't find any api to add it except modify the source code of golang.

The clientHelloMsg struct is private so i cant modify it.

So is there any way to add a custom extension to clientHellomsg?

Answer (score 3):

> So is there any way to add a custom extension to clientHellomsg ?

No. Except modifying the source/forking as you already seem to know.